# How can I make Google Now ignore some calendars for appointment reminders?

Tags: google-calendar, google-now

How can I make Google Now ignore some calendars?

My wife's calendar is shared to my calendar and then synced to my phone through my account and I currently get reminder cards for her events in Google Now.  I would like to only get cards for certain calendars.

Comment: Related: http://forums.androidcentral.com/google-samsung-galaxy-nexus/192983-disable-specific-calendar-events-appearing-google-now.html

Answer (score 11):

Apparently, Google Now uses the "My Calendars" section of Google Calendars.

When my wife's calendar was shared with me, I was granted "Make changes AND manage sharing" rights.   This puts the calendar into "My Calendars" for both users' calendars. When I changed it to "Make Changes to events" on my wife's sharing tab, the calendar moves from "My Calendars" to "Other Calendars" for my account and I no longer get notifications in Google Now for that calendar.

Comment: Thanks! Since you can't change your own sharing setting, I had to share it with another account, then change the setting on my main account from there, and then unsubscribe the other account :)

Comment: You would think there would be an easier solution.  I've been searching for this answer for 20 minutes!

Answer (score 4):

Instead of synchronizing her calendar to your phone, try setting her calendar "shared" and then subscribing to it from your own Google Calendar.  When you subscribe, I believe you can set it to not pull in the reminders.

Comment: +1 because you helped me find the solution.   Her calendar was shared, not synced via google sync.